# Two Routes for one Controller OR Two Routes for a group of actions

Tags: symfony, routes

Here is the scheme of the required URLs:

```
/service/getBalance    should map to CustomerController::getBalance
/service/addBalance    should map to CustomerController::addBalance

/customer/getBalance    should map to CustomerController::getBalance
/customer/addBalance    should map to CustomerController::addBalance
```

Here is a simple controller

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class CustomerController extends Controller {

    /**
     * @Route("/getBalance")
     */
    public function getBalanceAction(Request $request) {

    }

    /**
     * @Route("/addBalance")
     */
    public function addBalanceAction(Request $request) {

    }

} // class CustomerController
```

Have tried the following ways. None of them worked.

```
# rounting.yml
v1:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/CustomerController.php"
    prefix:   /service
    type:     annotation

v2:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/CustomerController.php"
    prefix:   /customer
    type:     annotation
```

loading the same resource with different prefix always overrides the previous occurrence (the last one works). The following also doesn't work for the same reason and have the same behavior.

```
# rounting.yml
v1:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing_customer.yml"
    prefix:   /service

v2:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing_customer.yml"
    prefix:   /customer


# routing_customer.yml
getBalance:
    path: /getBalance
    defaults : { _controller: "AppBundle:Customer:getBalance" }

addBalance:
    path: /addBalance
    defaults : { _controller: "AppBundle:Customer:addBalance" }
```

Third not working option:

```
# rounting.yml
v1:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing_v1.yml"
    prefix:   /     # evenr putting /service here instead of inside

v2:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing_v2.yml"
    prefix:   /     # evenr putting /customer here instead of inside

# routing_v1.yml
getBalance:
    path: /service/getBalance
    defaults : { _controller: "AppBundle:Customer:getBalance" }

addBalance:
    path: /service/addBalance
    defaults : { _controller: "AppBundle:Customer:addBalance" }

# routing_v2.yml
getBalance:
    path: /customer/getBalance
    defaults : { _controller: "AppBundle:Customer:getBalance" }

addBalance:
    path: /customer/addBalance
    defaults : { _controller: "AppBundle:Customer:addBalance" }
```

I actually need to route `/` and `/customer` to the same controller:
`/getBalance` and `/customer/getBalance`.

**I want to give two prefixes for a group of methods. How to do that in Symfony?**

### Conclusion from my trials, @goto's answer and @Cerad's comments:

The last Example above could have worked if I used different route names. Route names are unique though out the whole project (Not just unique in file). `v1_getBalance` and `v2_getBalance`.

The other solution is to use a [custom loader](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/custom_route_loader.html) as @goto described.

Comment: The first approach using annotations will not work since you have no annotations and annotations are strictly one route per method.  The second approach fails because you can only have one route per route name so the second overrides the first.  Keep it simple. Make a routing_customer.yml and a routing_service.yml and load them both.  The sad thing is that you will probably encounter other problems with trying to have one method handle two different requests.  I suspect that you will end up with two different controllers with slightly different code.

Comment: Methods can have two routes through annotations. I'm trying to find a better way of grouping them than repeating them in two files. I will have to write the prefix in front of each path!

Comment: @Cerad I've tried making two yml files but the second also overrides the first. Seems to me annotations is the only way to give a method two paths.

Comment: You need to give then different route names i.e. customer_get_balance and service_get_balance.  Pretend you are a router and it might make more sense.

Comment: Looks like route names are unique though out the project so I cannot have the same route name in two files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do routes this way:

```
     @Route(
          "/{subject}/getBalance",
          requirements={
              "subject": "customer|service"
          }
      )
```

in yml:

```
subject_getbalance:
  path:     /{subject}/getBalance
  requirements:
      subject:  customer|service
```

The requirement is safer than nothing: it allows you to route another route like `foo/getBalance` on another controller (as it does not match the requirement)

EDIT: for your special case, as you need /getBalance to map to your route too you could do:

```
subject_getbalance:
      path:     /{subject}/getBalance
      default: { _controller: YourBundle:Controller }
      requirements:
          subject:  customer|service
default_getbalance:
      path:     /getBalance
      default: { _controller: YourBundle:Controller, subject: customer }
```

Edit: the last idea is to a [custom route loader](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/custom_route_loader.html) (but I've never tried):

```
class ExtraLoader extends Loader
{
    public function load($resource, $type = null)
    {

       /* ... */

        $prefixes = [ 'default_' =>'','customer_' =>'/customer','service_' =>'/service']

        // prepare a new route
        $path = '/getbalance/{parameter}';
        $defaults = array(
            '_controller' => 'YourBundle:Actiona',
        );
        $requirements = array(
            'parameter' => '\d+',
        );
       foreach($prefixes as $prefixName => $prefixRoute) {
          $route = new Route($prefixRoute . $path, $defaults, $requirements);
          $routes->add($prefixName . 'getBalance', $route);
       }
```

This will allows you to have 3 routes generated:

```
default_getBalance: /getBalance
customer_getBalance: /customer/getBalance
service_getBalance: /service/getBalance
```

Comment: I tried to do that but my real case requires / and /customer to go to the controller
/getBalance
/customer/getBalance
I cannot do that with requirements. If you can tell me how.

Comment: This is what I'm trying to avoid. I will have to repeat every method routing twice!

Comment: See my last example .. I think it is the same as yours and sadly it is not working.

Comment: My last idea: using a /custom route loader.  Your last example is not same as mine as you will have 5 routes for 4 different prefix, and mine would only have 2.

Comment: From Symfony 4.1 you can prefix imported route names: https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-prefix-imported-route-names With this, you can one routing file, but imported it twice with different name prefix to avoid any route name to be overwritten